# RAM overload - itertools

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, python-itertools

Here’s a quick example of I’m trying to do and the error I’m getting:

```py
    for symbol in itertools.product(list_a, repeat=8):
        list_b.append(symbol)
```

I’m also afterwards excluding combinations from that list like so:

```py
    for combination in list_b:
        valid_b = True
        for symbols in range(len(list_exclude)):
            if list_exclude[symbols] in combination:
                valid_b = False
            else:
                pass
        if valid_b:
            new_list.append(combination)
```

I’ve heard somehow chunking the process might help, not sure how that could be done here though.

I’m using multiprocessing for this as well.

When I run it I get “MemoryError”

How would you go about it?

Comment: `itertools.product` with a `repeat` of 8 is going to produce massive iterables, which you're throwing into a big list. If `list_a` has only two elements, then `list_b` will have 256. If `list_a` has 10 elements, then `list_b` will have one hundred *million* elements. Even if each element only took one byte to store (which it very much does not), that's 100 MB already. Can you explain what problem you're trying to solve more generally? `repeat=8` is going to be a nightmare no matter how you look at it.

Comment: I have a set of 20 symbols, and I need to see every single possible combination, aside from a few that as I said I’m excluding. I have more than 500GB on my HDD (where I installed my python) so storage shouldn’t be an issue. But RAM is definitely a problem.

Comment: Okay, but why? What do you want to do with these sequences of symbols? It can't possibly be necessary to print them *all* to the screen or to a file. There must be some more efficient way of accomplishing whatever you're doing that doesn't require gigabytes of disk space to store the same twenty words in different orders.

Comment: I just need the combinations mate, there isn’t really anything more than that

Comment: Does the memory error occur during the first ```for``` loop or the second? Can you filter out the items that appear in ```list_exclude``` as you iterate the first loop, so those items never end up in ```list_b```? Avoiding the second list might solve your problem.

Comment: The error occurs during the very first for loop. So are you saying RAM usage is directly correlated with the list size? Also, would doing that slow down the process? I’m assuming something like this might take a will take a WHILE.

Comment: Well, yes, RAM usage would correlate with list size, so if you can add fewer items to the list, by filtering as you go, it might fit. It will take longer, but almost certainly no longer than it would have taken to filter the list in a separate step.

Comment: @sj95126 thing is, there’s just not that many exclusions to make a difference. Would writing the list into a notepad every few hundred items help solve the MemoryError?

Comment: You really need to add a [mcve]. The nature of `list_a` vs `list_exclude` are critical for an optimal solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pre-compute anything, especially not the first full list:

```
def symbols(lst, exclude):
    for symbol in map(''.join, itertools.product(lst, repeat=8)):
        if any(map(symbol.__contains__, exclude)):
            continue
        yield symbol
```

Now use the generator as you need to lazily evaluate the elements. Keep in mind that since it's pre-filtering the data, even `list(symbols(list_a, list_exclude))` will he much cheaper than what you originally wrote.

Here is a breakdown of what happens:

- `itertools.product` is a generator. That means that it produces an output without retaining a reference to any previous items. Each element it returns is a `tuple` containing some combination of the input elements.
- Since you want to compare strings, you need to convert the `tuple`s. Hence, `''.join`. Mapping it onto each of the `tuple`s that `itertools.product` produces converts those elements into strings. For example:

  ```
  >>> ''.join(('$', '$', '&', '&', '♀', '@', '%', '$'))
  '$$&&♀@%$'
  ```
- Filtering each `symbol` thus created can be done by checking if any of the items in `excludes` are contained in it. You can do this with something like

  ```
  [ex in symbol for ex in exclude]
  ```

  The operation `... in symbol` is implemented via the magic method `symbol.__contains__`. You can therefore `map` that method to every element of `exclude`.
- Since the first element of `exclude` that is contained in `symbol` invalidates it, you don't need to check the remainder. This is called short-circuiting, and is implemented in the `any` function. Notice that because `map` is a generator, the remaining elements will actually not be computed once a match is found. This is different from using a list comprehension, which pre-computed all the elements.
- Putting `yield` into your function turns it into a generator function. That means that when you call `symbols(...)`, it returns a generator object that you can iterate over. This object does not pre-compute anything until you call `next` on it. So if you write the data to a file (for example), only the current result will be in memory at once. It may take a long time to write out a large number of results but your memory usage should not spike at all from it.

Comment: Function parameter should be 'list_a' right? not 'lst'

Comment: Tried code below, didn't produce anything. Did I forget to import a module or something?

import itertools


lst = ['$','&','%','@','♀']
exclude = ['$$$','&&&','%%%','@@@','♀♀♀']

def symbols(lst, exclude):
    for symbol in itertools.product(lst, repeat=2):
        if any(map(symbol.__contains__, exclude)):
            continue
        yield symbol


symbols(lst, exclude)

Comment: @A.D. `symbols` returns a generator. Generators don't run until you ask for the elements. You need to do something like `for i in symbols(lst, exclude): print(i)` or `list(symbols(lst, exclude))`.

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to be working, I'm sure I must be missing something. Here: https://i.ibb.co/R0fLTBS/pyscreen.jpg

Comment: @A.D. Can't see that thru firewall. Please upload to stack.imgur. You can do that by editing your question, adding the image so it gives you a link, posting the link in a comment and then cancelling the edit.

Comment: @A.D. My mistake. I forgot to join the strings. Fixed now.

Comment: The result is now 315200 elements long, not 390625

Comment: Interesting, it does work now, some of these are still quite foreign to me so I pretty much have no idea what you did there, but it's at a point where I can make it very useful. So, let's say for every ITEM in this generator I use a FOR loop to write it to a text file. With a REPEAT of 8, do you think it would be fully executed? or still too heavy on RAM? (let's say I end up with 100MM elements, and exclude about 20MM, using an exclude list of around 100,000 combinations)

P.S. 35 symbols with repeat of 8

Comment: @A.D.  if you're writing to a file, I don't expect any issues at all besides taking a long time.

Comment: @A.D. Hope the update addresses some of your doubts.

Comment: Anyway you’d break this down into multiple processes or threads ? For example generating/iterating with 6 cores concurrently.

Comment: @A.D.  i suppose you could. If you're writing to a file, that would slow you down since the bottleneck is probably going to be IO

Comment: Hey, quick question, if I have multiple exclusion lists (6), do I add them all into the top of the function? --> def symbols(lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4, ..., ....): ?

Comment: @A.D.  Adding multiple lists like that would require another loop. Why not add them together: `symbols(lst1, lst2 + lst3 + lst4 + ...)`

Answer (score -1):

This little change i made could save you a bit of ram usage.

```py
    for combination in list_b:
        valid_b = True
        for symbols in list_exclude:
            if symbols in combination:
                valid_b = False
            else:
                pass
        if valid_b:
            new_list.append(combination)
```

Comment: The reason my code is the way it is, is because it has to exclude based on symbol matches that are not exact but contained. That wouldn’t work the way you wrote it

Comment: The whole point is to avoid creating `list_b`